# Unix console: Count distinct exceptions (not known beforehand)

Tags: unix, count, grep

Im trying to grep all occured exceptions in a log file (I do not know the exceptions beforehand) and evaluate their number of occurences. Heres an example to clarify what Im trying to achieve:

Consider the following log file:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ...
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: ...
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: ...
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: ...
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: ...
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ...
```

Of course the log file does not only consist of lines containing exceptions so there is also stuff that im not interested in (warnings, info and the likes)

I would like to get the following output (full qualified Exception name and number of occurences, order is irellevant):

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException 2
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException 1
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException 1
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException 2
```

I've come up with the following grep command/pattern to find all the exceptions but I cannot select the matching groups for further counting of occurences:

```
    grep -ioP --color "^[.*\.?]*(.*Exception):" myLogFile.log
```

Any advice is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to edit out the stuff after the colon, I'd use `sed` rather than `grep`, and then `sort` and `uniq -c`:

```
sed -n '/\(^[^:]*[eE]xception\):.*/s//\1/p' log-file |
sort |
uniq -c
```

This will give you the counts first, then the exception name; if you really need the counts second, then:

```
sed -n '/\(^[^:]*[eE]xception\):.*/s//\1/p' log-file |
sort |
uniq -c |
awk '{ print $2, $1}'
```

You can also sort into order of the frequency of the exceptions if you want (before or after the `awk` processing.

You could also do the whole job in just `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{ count[$1]++ } END { for (i in count) print i, count[i]; }' log-file
```

And given that `awk`, you can write it in Perl, too:

```
perl -F: -nae '$count{$F[0]}++; END {print "$_ $count{$_}\n" foreach (keys %count); }' log-file
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `awk`:

```
awk '{a[$1]++} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 1
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: 2
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: 2
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: 1
```